# PHP: array Formatting

Tags: php

I have array with duplicated mobile numbers with respective values, i want to merge those mobile numbers and with respective objects

and here is the actual syntax i have done

```
 foreach($char2['flowers_details'] as $flowers){
      foreach($array as $flowersd){
        if (in_array($flowers['flower_id'], $flowersd['flower_id'])){
          $details[] =  array('mobile'=>$flowersd['mobile'],'flower_name'=>$flowers['flower_name'],'flower_price'=>$flowers['flower_price']);
        }
    }
  }
 echo json_encode($details);
```

> Here is the response

```
[
{
    "mobile": "7799124599",
    "flower_name": "Merabel  ",
    "flower_price": "20"
},
{
    "mobile": "8008118599",
    "flower_name": "Merabel  ",
    "flower_price": "20"
},
{
    "mobile": "8008118599",
    "flower_name": "San maggi ",
    "flower_price": "10"
},
{
    "mobile": "7799124599",
    "flower_name": "Mango yellow  ",
    "flower_price": "50"
}]
```

this is not the perfect formate
and i have tried this syntax even though, I am not getting the exact formatted array

```
foreach($char2['flowers_details'] as $flowers){
      foreach($array as $flowersd){
          $mobile =  array('mobile'=>$flowersd['mobile']);    
        if (in_array($flowers['flower_id'], $flowersd['flower_id'])){
          $detail[] =  array('flower_name'=>$flowers['flower_name'],'flower_price'=>$flowers['flower_price']);
        }
        $details = array_merge($mobile,$detail);
    }
  }
echo json_encode($detail);
```

So, which way should i write the syntax to get perfect array formate
with show one number and other following values

Actual formate i want too show is

```
[
    [
        {
            "mobile": "7799124599"
        },
        {
            "flower_name": "Merabel  ",
            "flower_price": "20"
        },
        {
            "flower_name": "Mango yellow  ",
            "flower_price": "50"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "mobile": "8008118599"
        },
        {
            "flower_name": "Merabel  ",
            "flower_price": "20"
        },
        {
            "flower_name": "San maggi ",
            "flower_price": "10"
        }
    ]
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us a perfect format of your output array?

Comment: It might be useful if you told/showed us what you believe is **the perfect format** And showed us what the input array looks like as well if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your assignment code like below:-

```
$details[$flowersd['mobile']][] =  array('mobile'=>$flowersd['mobile'],'flower_name'=>$flowers['flower_name'],'flower_price'=>$flowers['flower_price']);
```

Above code will create mobile numbers as keys, so if you don't want that, then do this before `json_encode()`:-

```
$details = array_values($details); //will re-indexed array keys to 0,1,2,....
```